# How to check arraylist contains this particular word in android?

Tags: android, arraylist

I have `ArrayList<String>` in that I added 3-4 website names. Like, http://www.google.com, https://www.stackoverflow.com, etc. Now in my application if I type simply "google" then I want to compare that "google" word with the `ArrayList<String>`.

I am stuck here. Can anyone tell me how can I compare the string with the array object?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: If you want to do this without using loop, then you need to write your own ArrayList class. And write implementation of contains(). BUT at there you need loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

***To do so, you need to override implementation of `contains()`. I am giving you a simple example.***

*Custom ArrayList class*

```
public class MyArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2178228925760279677L;

    @Override
    public boolean contains(Object o) {
        return indexOf(o) >= 0;
    }

    @Override
    public int indexOf(Object o) {
        int size = this.size(); 
        if (o == null) {
            for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
                if (this.get(i) == null) {
                    return i; 
                }
            }
        } else {
           for (int i = 0; i < size ; i++) {
                if (this.get(i).contains(String.valueOf(o))) {
                    return i; 
                }
            }
        }
        return -1;
    }
}
```

How to use

```
MyArrayList arrayList = new MyArrayList(); 
arrayList.add("http://www.google.com");
arrayList.add("https://www.stackoverflow.com");
arrayList.add("http://pankajchunchun.wordpress.com");

if (arrayList.contains("google")) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList Contains google word");
}

if (arrayList.contains("igoogle")) {
    System.out.println("ArrayList Contains igoogle word");
} else {
    System.out.println("ArrayList does not Contains igoogle word");
}
```

Below is output for above code example

```
ArrayList Contains google word
ArrayList does not Contains igoogle word
```

See [***ArrayList Source Code***](http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/ArrayList.java) for more custom implementation.

Comment: Yes I am working in same only. Thank you so much. I guess it will work. +1 for you.

Answer (score 4):

`ArrayList.contains()` test the the String through equals. From the documentation:

> public boolean contains(Object o) Returns true if this list contains
>   the specified element. More formally, returns true if and only if this
>   list contains at least one element e such that (o==null ? e==null :
>   o.equals(e)).

example:

```
boolean contains = yourArrayListInstance.contains(yourString);
```

Edit. If you want to check for substring you have to loop on the ArrayList's content and call `String.contains`

Comment: Hey can you give me small example?

Comment: It seems anddev wants to check if one of the contained strings contains the substring.

Comment: anddev you want substring ?

Comment: @PankajKumar yes you are right contains is not working. We need to pass object as parameter of ArrayList.contains(). But I have only string value.

Answer (score 1):

You can iterate through your `ArrayList<String>` like

```
public String getWebsiteName(String toMatchString)
{
    ArrayList<String> yourArrayList = new ArrayList<String>();

    for (String webSiteName : yourArrayList)
    {
        if (webSiteName.contains(toMatchString))
            return webSiteName;
    }
    return null;
}
```

and get the matching `String`

Comment: Yes that's ture. But in my application I have so many data that I want to compare. So as a performance point of view for loop will not work for me.

Comment: Is there any other way using that I can get proper data? I search on google and I found that I can make Comparable<>. But I dont know how can I use that. Can you give me any example of that?

Comment: You will need to perform the `for` loop to get the `String` though you can take measures to prevent going into the `for` loop if the `String` does not exist in your `ArrayList`. For eg. change the `ArrayList` to `String` using `toString` and then check if your String to match exists in it or not.

Answer (score 0):

Use a helper function like this

```
public static boolean containsSubString(ArrayList<String> stringArray, String substring){
    for (String string : stringArray){
        if (string.contains(substring)) return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

Comment: The String string param is useless

Comment: Can I do this without using for loop?

Comment: @DoctororDrive sorry, corrected. And No, you need the loop.

Comment: @FD_ wrong again. The First parameter should be ArrayList, not String. And you must include a type to for loop.

Comment: @DoctororDrive Yeah, sorry, seems I was a bit confused, fixed now.